# Room Query not working

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-architecture

I'm trying to use **Room** with **LiveData** in my project. In my app, I have the **authors** table. The data is inserted fine but when I'm trying to read something from the table it did not give me records. I also see the database with SQLite Opener software. It shows me all the data.

Below is my Authors Entity.

```
@Entity(tableName = "authors")
    data class AuthorModel(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id") val id: Long = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name") var name: String
)
```

And this is my Author Dao interface.

```
@Dao
interface AuthorDao {

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM authors")
    fun allAuthors(): LiveData<List<AuthorModel>>

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM authors WHERE id = :authorId")
    fun authorWithId(authorId: Long): LiveData<AuthorModel?>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insert(author: AuthorModel): Long

}
```

And last, this is my RoomDatabase class.

```
@Database(entities = [AuthorModel::class], version = 1)
abstract class BookLibraryDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

abstract fun authorDao(): AuthorDao

}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: First check, your db file are present under /database/  folder?

Comment: @SaurabhKhare yes my DB exists in database folder. Like, I said above that the data inserted but I'm unable to read the data.

Comment: I have the same problem. I noticed that Room generated db file on android file system doesn't have .db extension as opposed to the SqlOpenHelper generated one, which has. So I guess it has something to do with the way Room generates db files.

Comment: It's something to do with returning LiveData. Try returning just `List<AuthorModel>` or `AuthorModel` (not wrapped in LiveData) and see if you have the same problem. I'm having the same issue in my app where returning LiveData doesn't work but returning the underlying data structure does.

Answer (score 2):

You have to observe LiveData. livedata.value will be null when you get first time.